# How can I show Notification using Bootstrap Modal in php

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

I would like to replace `echo "<script>alert('User is Logged In');</script>";` with `echo "<script>$('#modalNotification').modal()</script>";` in php, But it does not shows up in my browser.

The coding is shown below:

```
<?php 

    include('config/connect_database.php');

    $Username = '';

    if(isset($_POST['Login'])) {

        $Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Username']);
        $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Password']);

        $sql = "SELECT Username, Password, Authority FROM user WHERE Username LIKE '$Username' AND Status LIKE 'Active'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $username = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            mysqli_free_result($result);
            mysqli_close($conn);

            if(($Username === $username['Username']) && (password_verify($Password, $username['Password']))) {
                //echo "<script>alert('User is Logged In');</script>";
                echo "<script>$('#modalNotification').modal()</script>";

                session_start();
                $_SESSION['Username'] = $_POST['Username'];
                $_SESSION['Authority'] = $username['Authority'];

                echo "<script>location.href = 'home.php';</script>";
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('Invalid Username or Password');</script>";         
            }
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Invalid Username or Password');</script>";     
        }   

    }

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Management System</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="Source/pms_logo_blue.png" alt="Logo" style="width:50px;">
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </nav>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modalNotification" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalNotificationTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalNotificationTitle">NOTIFICATION</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="OK">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center py-5">
            <div class="col" style="max-width: 400px;">
                <h3 style="text-align: center;">Flinken Production Management System</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col" style="max-width:400px;">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="Username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Username); ?>" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Passsword</label>
                        <input type="password" name="Password" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="Login" value="True" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="section">
        <div class="text py-5" style="text-align: center">Copyright </div>
    </footer>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When doing echo “<script></script>” remove type part like in your original echo. And put included libraries at the top.

Comment: I had removed the type part in echo "<script></script>. Thank you

Comment: use this <script>$('#modalNotification').modal('show')</script>";

Comment: I had tried ```<script>$('#modalNotification').modal('show')</script>";``` . But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Latest Update:**

```
<?php session_start();
    include('config/connect_database.php');

    $Username = '';

    if(isset($_POST['Login'])) {

        $Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Username']);
        $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Password']);

        $sql = "SELECT Username, Password, Authority FROM user WHERE Username LIKE '$Username' AND Status LIKE 'Active'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $username = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            mysqli_free_result($result);
            mysqli_close($conn);

            if(($Username === $username['Username']) && (password_verify($Password, $username['Password']))) {

                $_SESSION['Username'] = $_POST['Username'];
                $_SESSION['Authority'] = $username['Authority'];

            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('Invalid Username or Password');</script>";         
            }
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Invalid Username or Password');</script>";     
        }   

    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Management System</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){?>$('#modalNotification').modal();<?php } ?> 
        $('div.modal button').click(function(){ location.href='home.php'; });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="Source/pms_logo_blue.png" alt="Logo" style="width:50px;">
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </nav>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modalNotification" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalNotificationTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalNotificationTitle">NOTIFICATION</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center py-5">
            <div class="col" style="max-width: 400px;">
                <h3 style="text-align: center;">Flinken Production Management System</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col" style="max-width:400px;">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="Username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Username); ?>" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Passsword</label>
                        <input type="password" name="Password" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="Login" value="True" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="section">
        <div class="text py-5" style="text-align: center">Copyright </div>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, the console shows that there are two errors:

1. ReferenceError: $ is not defined
2. None of the “sha384” hashes in the integrity attribute match the content of the subresource.

Comment: @SengKai That was because your PHP code was executed before the modal was created. Check the update.

Comment: Hi, nelsonrakson. I had tried it. the browser does blink once and go to home.php.  Yet, the errors still exists and the modal does not shows up.

Comment: @SengKai check the latest update of my answer for a complete working example. Don't forget to mark the answer if it solves your problem. Happy coding :-)

Comment: @SengKai you should also use mysqli prepared statement to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Cool, it is working. May i know what is the problem?

Comment: ,is it a good practice to put all the scripts in head tag or before </body> tag? does it affect the performance? Sorry to asking this because i am beginner just started this last 2 weeks.

Comment: @SengKai there are a lot of debate about this but I would advice you to always use the <head> section for light and important scripts your code cannot do without and bottom scripts for heavy and less important scripts. Your former approach failed because PHP echoed the script which made JS to try to interact with the modal which wasn't created yet. jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(e){})` solved the problem.

Comment: I see. Thank your for solving the problem and sharing. Have a nice day

Comment: @SengKai My pleasure!

Answer (score -1):

use **[Bootstrap JS Modal Method Show](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp)**

Replace this with

```
echo "<script>$('#modalNotification').modal()</script>";

echo "<script>$('#modalNotification').modal('show')</script>";
```